# Handling Browser Refresh in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am new ta GWT and I would like to know if there is a way to handler browser refresh. What happens now is that each time a user refreshes the page, or click F5, the application returns the user to the login page. what I want is to have the user stay at the same page when the page is refreshed. An example would be perfect.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Activities and Places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) design pattern for GWT.

It is a highly recommended approach that can handle page refreshes as well as back and forward buttons, and allows users to bookmark "pages" within your app.

Answer (score 0):

Along with looking at activities and places which is a very useful way of handling navigation in an ajax application you will also need to handle the session from the server. You would have a call to do authentication either through a realm or some kind of homegrown authentication. I recommend [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/java-authentication-guide.html) if you are just getting started. When you application loads from a refresh you need to make a call to the server to validate that the session you have is still valid and if so, you would send the user to the correct Place/Activity. The Activity/Places is a little bit more boiler plate but it is worth it in the long run and makes the application much more flexible. You may also want to checkout [Arcbees GWTP plugin](https://gwtp.arcbees.com/). This will handle most of the boilerplate for you but beware it can be a little complex to a newby. It uses Gin for dependecy injection and has some custom place mapping things that are a little different. But overall the documentation is very good and the gwtp eclipse plugin can save you some copying and pasting for some things.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the GWTP car store example. They did what you are looking for. https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/tree/master/gwtp-carstore

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to consider History Tokens in your development to handle adhoc F5 refresh problems. Please have a look at http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html. While changing from one screen/layout to other, History Tokens help your browser keep track of the changes, because History Tokens change the URL itself. Examples can be found in the shared link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Shishir. I was looking into History tokens, and I was wondering if they can work with buttons not only hyperlinks. Do you have any idea if this can be done?

Comment: Ofcourse you can do it with buttons. For that matter, with any widget's click event. Just use History.newItem(<String>) to change the url's history token and use the History.addValueChangeHandler to handle all your history tokens. You can go through the link I shared for deeper understanding. The method I describe takes care of your transitions as well as your browser history.